# Example Simple PHP MVC Projects

Tags: php, model-view-controller

What are some good examples of open source PHP projects built using the MVC architecture.

I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335197/best-open-source-mvc-php-project-to-study) which asks a similar question, but all the answers have focused on particular frameworks. I'm looking for actual built applications to use as case studies. I don't mind if the project uses these frameworks, but my focus is on the completed project, not how the framework works.

Comment: Drupal? Google doesn't work? This is not really a programming question. It's subjective at best. Maybe community wiki?

Comment: Sorry if this is not a good question. I've been using this site for reference and was hoping people here would know good projects. Google finds me lots of half completed or overly complex projects I can't understand. What does community wiki mean? You mean check wikipedia?

Comment: You can mark this question as a community wiki. What that means is that there is not one correct answer, but it is more of a wiki or discussion. This kind of question would fall into this category. If you mark it as such, people will feel free to post their ideas and suggestions even though it's not *the* correct answer.

Comment: @mario: I didn't know that. What do you mean by it's less rigid? It sounds like it is more rigid if you can't mark it as wiki. What would the correct answer to this question be? Should be be flagged as subjective and argumentative? That might be harsh.

Comment: @sims Actually, he *can't* mark it community wiki, that isn't how community wiki works. It was specifically changed so that people would *stop* posting "zomg community wiki now!" comments. Hint hint.

Comment: I get the point. However, this is not really a programming question that has *a correct answer*.

Answer (score 0):

The [SleekMVC](https://github.com/renownedmedia/sleekmvc) framework comes with a sample application...